# Multimodule Gradle projects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I'm currently building a client-server app with multiple distributed apis (via Java Spring Boot), and I've abstracted the API components (@Controller, @Service @Mapper, and @Repository).

I have a multi-module gradle project that looks something like this:

```
---- Projects
------ properties.gradle
------ settings.gradle
------ ClientProj
-------- ClientApplication
-------- build.gradle
------ ApiProj1
-------- ApiProj1Application
-------- build.gradle
------ ApiProj2
-------- ApiProj2Application
-------- build.gradle
------ common
-------- build.gradle
------ api-components
-------- build.gradle
```

But I want to possibly do something like this instead:
(Notice that I'm trying to wrap all the api related components together).

```
---- Projects
------ properties.gradle
------ settings.gradle
------ ClientProj
-------- ClientApplication
-------- build.gradle
------ common
-------- build.gradle
------ api
-------- ApiProj1
---------- ApiProj1Application
---------- build.gradle
-------- ApiProj2
---------- ApiProj2Application
---------- build.gradle
------- api-components
---------- build.gradle
```

From what I've seen online, I haven't noticed multimodes *within* other modules like the last example I show with the api. I'd like to ask everyone whether this design is acceptable, and if so, whether these nested api modules would be considered subprojects. From my unsuccessful attempts thus far, it seems really difficult to access nested projects when constructed this way.

I'm a bit more than beginner for using Gradle but multimodules and subprojects are new to me and I think has a lot of potential to isolate concerns and organize code. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's still possible to use the second structure. Your first structure's `settings.gradle.kts` must be like:

```
include(
    "ClientProj",
    "common",
    "ApiProj1",
    "ApiProj2",
    "api-components",
)
```

For the second, it should be changed to:

```
include(
    "ClientProj",
    "common",
    "ApiProj1",
    "ApiProj2",
    "api-components",
)

project(":ApiProj1").projectDir = file("api/ApiProj1")
project(":ApiProj2").projectDir = file("api/ApiProj2")
project(":api-components").projectDir = file("api/api-components")
```

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't think you could have more than one settings.gradle file. I'll try this out and let you know how it works!

Comment: no, it's only one settings.gradle.

Comment: I mean you should change the file like that.